# Kubernetes: Issues with liveness / readiness probe on S3 storage hosted Docker Registry

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, helm

#### Current setup

Hello. I'm using a Docker Registry helm chart deployed with an S3 storage. Now I would like to update (change) the way the live/readiness probes work. The reason being that after one day of use, I have depleted the free tier **monthly** quota of LIST requests on AWS. This quota is 2000 requests/mo. Right now, the probes on the registry pod look like this:

```
Liveness:       http-get http://:5000/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
Readiness:      http-get http://:5000/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
```

These requests are obviously `GET`. However, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241679/amazon-s3-what-are-considered-put-copy-post-list-request) answer, these requests are tagged as `LIST` by AWS.

These are the custom values (**chart_values.yaml**) I have used in the helm chart Docker Registry installation:

```
storage: s3

secrets:
  htpasswd: "..."
  s3:
    accessKey: "..."
    secretKey: "..."

s3:
  region: "..."
  secure: true
  bucket: "..."
```

Pushing / pulling of images works as expected.

#### Question (see the latest edit for the rephrased question)

- <strike>What should I do to avoid getting the S3 queried by the probes?</strike>
- <strike>Shouldn't the liveness/readiness checks be related only to the pod itself without touching the S3?</strike>

I know I can edit the deployment config to change the `periodSeconds` of the probes, to let's say `600s`. But I don't think that is the optimal solution. I'm aware that [liveness commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) exist, but I'm not sure if this would be possible with the default registry docker image.

Last thing I thought of was that maybe if the registry docker image had prometheus metrics enabled, I would be able to change the probes to the `:5001/metrics` path. But I'm not really sure how to do that.

---

**EDIT**:

To enable the prometheus metrics I have removed my previous helm installation of docker registry. Then downloaded the [stable docker reigstry helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/docker-registry) via `helm pull stable/docker-registry --untar`.

Then I have edited the **templates/deployment.yaml** file:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5000
      - containerPort: 5001     # Added this line
    livenessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 1    # Added
      path: /metrics            # Edited
      port: 5001                # Edited
    readinessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 10   # Added
      path: /metrics            # Edited
      port: 5001                # Edited
    env:
      # Added these env variables
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_ADDR
        value: "localhost:5001"
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED
        value: "true"
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_PROMETHEUS_PATH
        value: /metrics
```

And **templates/service.yaml** file:

```yaml
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      protocol: TCP
      name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
      targetPort: 5000
    # Added these lines below
    - port: 5001
      protocol: TCP
      name: {{ .Values.service.name }}-prometheus
      targetPort: 5001
```

Lint and install:

```sh
helm install registry ./docker-registry-chart/ -f chart_values.yaml -n docker-registry
```

However, the registry pod is never *ready* with this configuration (`kubectl get` shows 0/1 on the pod). This is due to the readiness probe failing because the 5001 containerPort doesn't get exposed. Thus, the readiness probe fails without being able to reach the metrics server.

I can confirm that the metrics server in the Docker container starts up properly. Here are the registry pod logs that show that the debug (metrics) server is up:

```
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5000_TCP" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5000_TCP_PORT" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5000_TCP_PROTO" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5001_TCP" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5001_TCP_ADDR" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5001_TCP_PORT" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5001_TCP_PROTO" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVICE_HOST" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVICE_PORT" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVICE_PORT_REGISTRY" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVICE_PORT_REGISTRY_PROMETHEUS" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.172115809Z" level=info msg="debug server listening localhost:5001" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.188154917Z" level=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=fc945824-3600-4343-8a18-75a20b07f695 service=registry version=v2.7.1 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.194453749Z" level=info msg="Starting upload purge in 29m0s" go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=fc945824-3600-4343-8a18-75a20b07f695 service=registry version=v2.7.1 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.211140816Z" level=info msg="using inmemory blob descriptor cache" go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=fc945824-3600-4343-8a18-75a20b07f695 service=registry version=v2.7.1 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.211497166Z" level=info msg="providing prometheus metrics on /metrics" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.211894294Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:5000" go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=fc945824-3600-4343-8a18-75a20b07f695 service=registry version=v2.7.1
```

I can even exec into the docker container and curl `localhost:5001/metrics` which results in 200 with the appropriate prometheus data.

But I'm still **not sure how to expose the 5001 port on the container**. I believe this would allow me to use metrics with the probes like [@mdaniel](https://serverfault.com/users/330715/mdaniel) mentions in [his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1011691/568415).

---

**EDIT 2**:

```
kubectl port-forward <registry_pod> 5001
```

Portforwarding the registry pod works and I can `curl localhost:5001/metrics` to get the prometheus metrics data. `curl` is executed from the cluster.

I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my **templates/service.yaml** file..?

---

**EDIT 3**: I have figured out what the problem was. The inaccessible service on port `5001` was caused by improperly setting the `REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_ADDR` to `localhost:5001`. The **value should be `:5001`**.

Finally, to translate this into how your **templates/deployment.yaml** should look like:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5000
      - containerPort: 5001     # Added this line
    livenessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 1    # Added
      path: /metrics            # Edited
      port: 5001                # Edited
    readinessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 10   # Added
      path: /metrics            # Edited
      port: 5001                # Edited
    env:
      # Added these env variables
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_ADDR
        value: ":5001"          # Make sure the addr field is left empty!
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED
        value: "true"
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_PROMETHEUS_PATH
        value: /metrics
```

Potentially you could also supply the environment variables through the **chart_values.yaml** file with the `configData` section (`configData.http.debug.addr` etc.).

---

Either way, I have decided to post the "*answer*" as an edit as opposed to a regular SO answer. **The original question is still unanswered.**

**To rephrase the original question**:

- Shouldn't the liveness/readiness checks be related only to the pod itself without accessing the S3? The S3 health check should be customizable with the [storagedriver](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#storagedriver) on the registry container. To me it seems like the registry is a separate entity almost unrelated to the S3. Essentially we want to health check that entity, not the data storage which has a separate health check...

Answer (score 0):

> I would be able to change the probes to the :5001/metrics path. But I'm not really sure how to do that

Since you didn't specify how you installed anything, no one can give you the specific commands, but I checked [the docker-registry helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/docker-registry/templates/deployment.yaml#L57-L70) and it appears they do not allow customization of the liveness and readiness probes :-(

So you will have to use `kubectl edit deploy $registry_deploy` where `$registry_deploy` is the Deployment name that is running registry, then update the two probes blocks to specify what you want.

Just be aware that while the `/metrics` endpoint is a perfectly fine liveness probe, it actually is doing the correct thing by poking S3 during *readiness* probe since the Pod should not be serving traffic if it can't correctly connect to S3 with the credentials it has available to it.

Comment: Hey. I've tried to update the probes to query `:5001/metrics` instead of `:5000/` and also updated my question with an edit. Care to take a look? Thanks :)